# CommunicationException while using the Atlassian .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, jira-ondemand

I'm using the Atlassian .NET SDK to extract data from Jira OnDemand. I need to get more than 100 issues for a particular project. My problem is that if I set the maxIssues property to higher than `67`, I get a `CommunicationExceptions` saying:

> "Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'getIssuesFromJqlSearch'."

Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
var jiraConn = new Jira(url, user, password);

IEnumerable<Atlassian.Jira.Issue> jiraIssues = 
     jiraConn.GetIssuesFromJql("project = MAGNAMES", 67);

foreach (var i in jiraIssues)
{
    MessageBox.Show(i.Key + " " + i.Summary);
}
```

> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>   Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at Atlassian.Jira.Remote.JiraSoapService.getIssuesFromJqlSearch(getIssuesFromJqlSearchRequest request)
>      at Atlassian.Jira.Remote.JiraSoapServiceClient.Atlassian.Jira.Remote.JiraSoapService.getIssuesFromJqlSearch(getIssuesFromJqlSearchRequest request) in c:\dev\atlassian.net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Remote\JiraSoapService.cs:line 9445
>      at Atlassian.Jira.Remote.JiraSoapServiceClient.getIssuesFromJqlSearch(String in0, String in1, Int32 in2) in c:\dev\atlassian.net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Remote\JiraSoapService.cs:line 9454
>      at Atlassian.Jira.Remote.JiraSoapServiceClientWrapper.GetIssuesFromJqlSearch(String token, String jqlSearch, Int32 maxNumResults) in c:\dev\atlassian.net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Remote\JiraSoapServiceClientWrapper.cs:line 39
>      at Atlassian.Jira.Jira.<>c__DisplayClass8.<GetIssuesFromJql>b__7(String t) in c:\dev\atlassian.net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Jira.cs:line 203
>      at Atlassian.Jira.Jira.<>c__DisplayClass37.<WithToken>b__36(String t) in c:\dev\atlassian.net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Jira.cs:line 396
>      at Atlassian.Jira.Jira.<>c__DisplayClass3d`1.b__3c(String token, IJiraSoapServiceClient client) in c:\dev\atlassian.net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Jira.cs:line 427
>      at Atlassian.Jira.Jira.WithToken[TResult](Func`3 function) in c:\dev\atlassian.net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Jira.cs:line 446
>      at Atlassian.Jira.Jira.WithToken[TResult](Func`2 function) in c:\dev\atlassian.net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Jira.cs:line 427
>      at Atlassian.Jira.Jira.WithToken(Action`1 action) in c:\dev\atlassian.net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Jira.cs:line 394
>      at Atlassian.Jira.Jira.GetIssuesFromJql(String jql, Nullable`1 maxIssues) in c:\dev\atlassian.net-sdk\Atlassian.Jira\Jira.cs:line 201
>      at TicketReportService.ReportService.StartService() in c:\OSSTicketReportApp\TicketReportWebApp\TicketReportService\ReportService.cs:line 92
>      at TicketReportService.Program.Main() in c:\OSSTicketReportApp\TicketReportWebApp\TicketReportService\Program.cs:line 24
>      at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>      at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: This sounds like it might be a limitation in the Jira api.  Can you add the stack trace?  If it is a built in limitation, sounds like you'll need to paginate your self to get all of the issues.

Comment: @PhilipPittle I added the stack trace. If you look at the link below, the creator of the SDK suggests using a query and then Take(100) so according to that you should be able to get more than 67 results from a query. Therefore I hope it's not a limitation in the Jira api.https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk-hg/issue/2/only-20-issues-per-search

Comment: Another option is that issue number 68 contains some information that the `JiraSoapService` is unable to deserialize because of a formatting issue.  You could try deleting this item and then recreating it later.  Or use Fiddler to pull down the response from requesting 100 items and manually remove number 68.

Comment: @PhilipPittle You are right! There's something wrong with this particular issue. I created a query that only retrieves this issue but it throws the CommunicationException as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Excellent, will leave it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure there isn't a particular problem with Issue number 68 that is preventing `JiraSoapService` from correctly deserializing the issue.  Perhaps there is something in a comment or other WYSIWYG field that is breaking the deserializer.